# An inbox JSON object cannot be initialized?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to create a JSON inbox object in Java.

```
 public class GetContacts extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws ServletException, IOException{
    try{
        String list = req.getParameter("list");
        String profileId = "27";
        //Accessing driver from the JAR file 
        Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  

        //Connect to Clockie's database
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cdatabase", "root", "root");

        //Here we create our query
        String sql =
                "SELECT * " +
                "FROM messages " +
                "WHERE profileId = ?";
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, profileId);
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        JSONArray messages = new JSONArray();
        while(result.next()){
            JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
            message.put("to", result.getString("to"));
            message.put("from", result.getString("from"));
            message.put("message", result.getString("message"));
            message.put("profileId", profileId);
            messages.put(message);
        }
        System.out.println(messages.toString());


        resp.setContentType("text/javascript");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        String output = req.getParameter("callback") + "(" + messages.toString() + ");";
        out.write(output);
        out.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

But I got the following error message:

> The local variable messages have not been initialzied

What have I done wrong?

The JSON classes I use is the original ones in http://www.json.org/java/

BTW, I'm using Eclipse as my IDE

Ok, I think I located the problem. The JSON library I added got an error when I tried to export the Jar file. And the error appeared in JSONArray class. How do you export JSON library to jar files in Eclipse?

This is how I did and got some warning(The warning was in the JSONArray class):

`Ok created a new project and right click -> export -> choose Jar Files (under java folder) -> marked both .classpath and .project in the right rectangle -> I selected a random destination folder with the filname org.json.jar. When I did this i got some warnings`

Never mind the location of the problem. I tried to define instead the variable messages the variable `messagesss` as a JSONArray obj. I still got the same error with `message` not `messagessss`. But how do I correct this problem?

The java class is under a package called messages, is this the problem?

Comment: isn't this line which initializes the array
>JSONArray messages = new JSONArray();

Comment: @Woh, yup.  That's why I don't think there should be a problem.  Have you done a clean build?

Comment: Does it say what line number is causing the error message?

Comment: I'm new to java but if this error: (java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: |?The local variable messages may not have been initialized|
 at messages.GetContacts.doGet(GetContacts.java:43)...) means line 43 then it is this line which is causing it JSONObject message = new JSONObject();

Comment: How do I quote in comments by the way I tried >

Comment: @jjnguy: What's a clean build?

Comment: 2Woho Are you used two variables with name messages? Because messages.GetContacts is not a JSONArray`s method

Comment: @woh, to make comments look like code use a ` (back tic) symbol to surround the code.

Comment: @Xupypr MV: I added the entire code sample, look above. @jinguy: ok thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If clean+build can't help try to refresh your project or restart you IDE. I copy this code in my Eclipse and there are not any problems.

Comment: how do I refresh my project and how do I clean build? I'm using Eclipse btw. they build automatically?

Comment: I think you have another problem: multiple variables with same name. Check the question comments.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. At least as I can see there is no more variables called `messages`

Comment: Never mind the location of the problem. I tried to define instead the variable `messages` the variable `messagesss` as a JSONArray obj. I still got the same error with `message` not `messagesss`so I think you´re right it hasn't refreshed. But how do I correct this problem